# Xcode 6.4 "Could not download and install iOS 8.3 simulator"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

I've been trying to install iOS simulators 8.3 & 8.4 on Xcode 6.3.2 an 6.4 beta respectively. In the first case is not even an option to download this simulator while in Xcode 6.4 it shows an error "Could not download and install iOS 8.3 Simulator. Authorization is required to install the packages". I've searched the web but I could not find anything so I tries reinstalling Xcode from Apple developer website as well as from the app store with no change at all. The only simulator I can use is 8.2. I cannot install any other version. Any help would be really appreciated.

This is the error on Xcode 6.4 with no additional option of iOS 8.4 Simulator
[image: Xcode 6.4 beta]

These are the simulator options for me to download which result in that error
[image]

These are my options in Xcode 6.3.2 with no option for iOS 8.3
[image: Xcode 6.3.2]

Comment: 8.3 is the default for Xcode 6.3.2 so it doesn't need to be downloaded. As for the first message, are your AppleID and password correctly entered in the "Accounts" section?

Comment: @cbiggin yes.. and I am the iOS and Mac "agent". Even though it should be already installed, when I run the project it only runs on the iOS 8.2 simulator. When I select as minimum deployment target iOS 8.3 it errors that I should select a lower version as "iPhone 6 runs iOS 8.2 which is lower than -project name- minimum deployment target. Change your project's minimum deployment target or upgrade iPhone 6's version of iOS".

Comment: Also under window/devices it has only iOS 8.2 simulator

Comment: I put a bugreport in for this: 22644731

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 7 (Beta 3 & 4) Could not download and install iOS 8.\* simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396936/xcode-7-beta-3-4-could-not-download-and-install-ios-8-simulator)

Comment: @mixel: how did it become the duplicate? this was asked 3months ago while  the post in your link is 2months ago?

Comment: @0yeoj That question has the same but accepted answer with more upvotes. Also it have more specific title that is better googled.

Comment: @mixel: That doesn't make this post a duplicate. You should have suggested for an edit instead.

Comment: @0yeoj But they are the same. And I just voted and not closed post as duplicate.

Comment: @mixel: Okay let me rephrase that, "That doesn't make this post **the** duplicate.". because it is not the duplicate, this is the original.. there i've said it.. the original.. ;)

Comment: @0yeoj Ok, I retracted my vote and edited title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found [a workaround on the Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/51550#51550).  If you run Xcode using `sudo` the simulator downloads and installs work just fine:

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Note: Once the downloads and installs are complete you should quit Xcode and start it normally.

Comment: Also if you renamed your Xcode( Xcode 6.4 for example), it would be:
`sudo /Applications/"Xcode 6.4.app"/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`

Answer (score 6):

The iOS 8.3 Simulator runtime is includes in Xcode 6.3 (which is why it isn't offered as an additional download).

The iOS 8.3 Simulator runtime should be downloadable from Xcode 6.4, as you show.  Your dialog box reports that there was an authentication problem when attempting to install the package.  You need to provide administrator credentials when installing the package.

The reason you are getting your "iPhone 6 runs iOS 8.2 which is lower than -project name- minimum deployment target." errors is because you are selecting an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.2 on it and not an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3 on it.

Use 'xcrun simctl create' or Xcode's Devices window to create the iOS 8.3 devices you need.

Comment: I have the same authorization error when installing any simulator, but it asks me to provide administrator credentials when a simulator starts to download. So I can't install any simulator in Xcode 7, and also can't launch Xcode 6 in OS X 10.11 Beta 3. Tried to reinstall Xcode 7, but it didn't help.

Comment: Xcode 6 is not supported in OS X 10.11.  You need to use Xcode 7 or later.  As you stated, it asks you to provide credentials.  If you are not able to do so yourself, you should have an administer install it for you.

Comment: The thing is, I'm the only user of my Mac and enter the correct password, then it starts to download the simulator. Once it's done downloading it tries to start installing the simulator and shows me this error.

Comment: Ok, then that sounds different.  Please file a radar with relevant logging (and a screencap would be helpful too) at http://bugreport.apple.com ... Make sure to include /var/log/install.log and system.log

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I put a link to this question in my bug report?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? This still occurs to me in Xcode 7 Beta 6 @Randex

Comment: @Chris I suspect your current issue might be this other one which is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137582/how-to-install-ios-7-and-onwards-simulators-in-xcode-7-beta-5?noredirect=1#comment52320646_32137582

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I'm afraid not no, I'm getting the same 'Authorization is required to install packages' error message like above. Should I create a new radar for it?