# How to install iOS 7 and onwards simulators in Xcode 7 Beta 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

I want to test my app on iOS 7 and onwards. The only way to test my app in these OS' are using Simulator. But after upgrading my Xcode to 7 Beta, I see the iOS 8.1, 8.2, 8.3 but I get an error that they are not found. iOS7 is non existing. Is there any way to install the older OS simulators in Xcode 7 beta 5?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on your "error that they are not found" comment.  Please provide a screenshot showing the exact error dialog and indicate what application is showing the error.

Comment: I have attached the screenshots including the error. Any pointers?

Comment: It looks like you have the older (Xcode 6) versions of the 8.3 sim runtime in which liblauch_sim.dylib was not signed in a way that would be usable by new security requirements in Xcode 7.  There are newer versions available for Xcode 7.  They SHOULD be shown in that preference pane.  Obviously they arent.  Please file a radar and leave a comment here with the radar number.  Goto http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Does anyone know if you can debug from an iPhone 4 (running iOS 7) via a USB cable?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Older Simulator runtimes are available for download through Xcode's preferences.

Goto Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads to see the list of compatible legacy simulator runtimes.

El Capitan supports iOS 8.1 and newer runtimes.

Yosemite supports iOS 7.1 and newer runtimes.

There is a known issue mentioned in the Xcode release notes which prevents the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime from working in Xcode 7.

Thus, you can't currently use the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime with Xcode 7.

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads shows empty list. It shows only documentation, which are all downloaded. I believe I accidentally deleted them and now I cannot download them anymore.

Comment: If you see none, you should file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com including /var/log/system.log and a screenshot.

Comment: Your answer is contradicting itself; initially, you claim that you can install the simulator from preferences, then claim that it's not possible on Xcode 7.

Comment: @Zorayr It is not contradictory.  You can download the 8.x legacy sims, not 7.1.

Comment: Updated the answer to mention that at this point, there is *no way* to install iOS7.x simulators on Xcode 7 — if you find a way, I would love to know.

Comment: The answer was correct and more informative before you changed it.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia cant we do the old trick of getting an old version of xcode with iOS7 simulator, navigating to Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > SDKs, then copying the iPhoneSimulator 7 folder then pasting it into the same location of the xcode 7 package contents??

Answer (score 0):

Click on device selection tab then click on more Simulator after then you can select and install ios Simulator from new open window.

Answer (score -2):

You can Download it. or if you have already in your Older Xcode Version then you have to Manage it from

> **Window > Device**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I click on Window->Devices. Then what do you do to come to Create a new simulator screen?

Comment: click on Plus button given below

Comment: Yes. But this doesn't help me. I can create as many simulators as I want. They don't work. Files are missing I think and it does not let me download them.

Comment: @then please delete Xcode and install new one , Download Latest and Install it then follow step. it may be work

Comment: try it once. then inform me, i will help you to find another soolution