# Xcode 7 GM missing iOS 7 simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator

I've upgraded my Xcode 7 beta version to Xcode 7 GM but I am missing iOS 7.1 simulators. I still have Xcode 6 and I can use 7.1 simulators there. I tried to look in `Preferences -> Downloads` but there are only 8.x simulators.

I have `Deployment Target` set to 7.0. I can get app working with 7.1 simulator in Xcode 7 beta 6.

So where is the problem? Before final release Apple remove 7.x simulators but I'll find them with production release? Is it possible to enable these simulators now? Thanks

**Edit:**
I was looking at directory with Xcode 6

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

and I have there only `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` and `iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk` which reference to first one. In Xcode 7 I have same situation with two folders `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` and `iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk`. So where is 7.1 Simulator folder? Is it possible that it is somewhere else? Because as I wrote I have 7.1 as options for simulators and when I go to `Preferences -> Downloads` in Xcode 6 I have 7.1 simulators downloaded.

If Xcode 7 don't get 7.x simulators then how can I test my apps to 7.x iOS when I want to use Xcode 7 Swift 2.0 for development? And when I don't have any device with iOS 7.x

Comment: Although the following SO Q may state Xcode 7 beta 5, the answer given also applies to Xcode 7 GM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32145114/1470581 There's also a similar post on the Apple Developer Forum with an answer from the same gentleman who states that iOS7.1 simulators are not supported on Xcode 7.x: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23620

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find iOS 7.x simulator in the newer version of Xcode as Apple tends to only keep the most recent one with their newer Xcode version.  I think you will have to install an older version of Xcode that supports this older version of iOS/simulator, which is available from Apple's developer website.  You can install Xcode (old) in `/Applications` by renaming it so it doesn't conflict with your current version.  Yes it is possible to have more than one version of Xcode on your machine if they do not have the same name!  Then, look in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

using the console and simply do a copy/paste of the simulator from the old Xcode to the new one.  I have no idea if this will work with the newest version, but it used to in the past.  Be careful though as Mac App Store has issues detecting which Xcode is the new one and might overwrite the version you don't want if you decide to upgrade.

**EDIT:**
How about here?

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know about this option to have installed both Xcode and that's exactly what I have ;) I have edited my question because I can't find 7.1 simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Add iPhoneOS7.1.sdk to path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs"
You need to get iPhoneOS7.1.sdk from XCode 6.4