# How to launch app using Xcode 7.1 with iOS Deployment target iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, ios7.1

I want to launch my app for users who have iOS 7.1 and ahead. After installing Xcode 7.1 after running on iOS 7.1 simulator its giving

```
The iOS 7.1 simulator runtime is not available.

Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib. Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime.
```

After reading solutions of

[How can I run the iOS 7.1 Simulator in Xcode 7.0 beta 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056634/how-can-i-run-the-ios-7-1-simulator-in-xcode-7-0-beta-2)

As you can see in comments also with El capitan and Xcode 7.1 its not working.

**The only thing which i want here is my app should be available for iOS 7.1 and ahead users.**

Comment: You need to test with real device has the 7.1 version. In simulator its not possible

Comment: Here is a hack that may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32513587/656600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a device with iOS 7.1 to check your app. If you have deployment target set to 7.1 it should run on that device with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Older Simulator runtimes are available for download through Xcode's preferences.

Goto Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads to see the list of compatible legacy simulator runtimes.

**El Capitan supports iOS 8.1 and newer runtimes.**

**Yosemite supports iOS 7.1 and newer runtimes.**

There is a known issue mentioned in the Xcode release notes which prevents the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime from working in Xcode 7.

Thus, you can't currently use the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime with Xcode 7.