# iOS7 Simulator in XCode7 live version?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

I cant see iOS7 simulator in Settings/Downloads/Components. How can I run my app on iOS7 simulator? I need to make sure everything works on ios7-9!

Comment: until now I've only found that an old iPhone 4 running iOS 7 is the only option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install iOS 7 and onwards simulators in Xcode 7 Beta 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137582/how-to-install-ios-7-and-onwards-simulators-in-xcode-7-beta-5)

Comment: @EricD. Difference is this is about the Live version not a beta version and its still not there.

Comment: What does "live version" mean? If you're talking about the released version, yes Xcode 7 is available in the App Store, it's no more in beta. And having read the page I linked to, it seems like an accurate answer for you. Have you tried? If it doesn't work then edit your question explaining why the duplicate doesn't apply here and in this case I will remove the vote to close.

Comment: @EricD. I agree that it's not a duplicate. Even Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia's answer there emphasizes that it applies only to the _current_ version of the beta. Only now do we know that that it applies to _final_ version of Xcode 7.

Comment: @matt Ok, I understand your point. I've removed the vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I run my app on iOS7 simulator?

To make a long story short, you can't. You can't use the iOS 7 simulator with Xcode 7. You can use the iOS 7 simulator with Xcode 6, but you can't build your app there. This is in keeping with Apple's stated policy of helping you be backward compatible *only one major version backward*.

The only solution, therefore is either to give up your goal of backward compatibility to iOS 7 or to test on an iOS 7 device.

Comment: Why do apple do this to us? ;(

Comment: Because they make their money from selling hardware. Apple is a hardware company. They need people with devices that can't be upgraded beyond iOS 7 to buy new devices.

Comment: Not if you bought Apple stock in 2006, it isn't... :)

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode 7 Release Notes call out that the iOS 7 Simulator is not supported.