# How to install iOS simulators from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-simulator

It's a common case to run tests against different versions of iOS simulators/SDKs on CI. However, only the latest iOS simulator is installed by Xcode on default.

So I need install other missing iOS simulators from command line in CI environment. But I cannot find a way to install those simulators from command line.

Comment: When you install Xcode it already installed iOS simulators. Do you want commands to run from the command line?

Comment: Do you want to *create simulator devices* or *install legacy simulator runtimes*?

Comment: Install simulator runtimes

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It can be done with [xcode-install](https://github.com/neonichu/xcode-install), with the following commands

```
gem install xcode-install
xcversion simulators --install='iOS 9.3'
```

Comment: If you need to do this in your CI and handle the password prompt, try:

echo "" | xcversion simulators --install='iOS 10.3.1'

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work for me, i have Xcode 10.1 and xcversion 2.5.0. The output is `Installing iOS 11.2 Simulator for Xcode 10.1.0...
[!] Failed to download iOS 11.2 Simulator.`

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem work anymore under XCode 14.1.

Comment: xcversion simulators --install='iOS 16.4'
[!] No simulator matching iOS 16.4 was found. Please specify a version from the following available simulators:
Xcode 15.0.1 (/Applications/Xcode.app)

Answer (score 4):

```
xcrun simctl create <name> <device type> <runtime>
```

For example:

```
xcrun simctl create "ry" "iPhone 11 Pro Max" iOS13.3
```

`xcrun simctl` is command utils to control iOS simulator, just like `adb` for Android. You can also run `xcrun simctl help`, there are a bundle of useful subcommands. When successful, most of these commands exit with 0; when failed, most exit with a non-zero number.

Personally, I have an [article](https://suelan.github.io/2020/02/05/iOS-Simulator-from-the-Command-Line/) about how to use simulator from terminal.

Comment: it is giving error: - Invalid runtime: iOS13.3

Comment: try to use a runtime you installed locally.   run `xcrun simctl list` to see available runtime in your laptop

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8.1 Simulator:
http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_1-8.1.1.1434581536.dmg

For iOS 8.2 Simulator:
http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_2-8.2.1.1434581536.dmg

For iOS 8.3 Simulator:
http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_3-8.3.1.1434581536.dmg

For iOS 8.4 Simulator:
http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_4-8.4.1.1435785476.dmg

I don't know where these URLs come from, but I found some clues

- https://gist.github.com/masbog/bf6e2d6fce80447396eb

Answer (score 1):

1. Download a simulator `.dmg` file from the Apple Developer Portal
2. Install the simulator using a command: `xcrun simctl runtime add <path to DMG file>`

Answer (score 0):

FYI

All simulators are packed with Xcode app. Instead of installing simulators you can just install the specific Xcode versions.
Xcode7.0 has iOS9 Simulators
Xcode6.4 has iOS8.x Simulators

In your CI testing if you want to test you app for a specific simulator just select xcode version before you do the xcodebuild command

```
xcode-select -switch <path to your xcode app>
```

This will set your default xcode to run the xcodebuild
Then run the xcodebuild with your respective simulator.

```
xcodebuild -configuration ${BUILD_TYPE} -target ${TARGET_NAME} -arch ${CPU_ARCHITECTURE} -sdk ${SIMULATOR_OR_IOS_SDK}
```

In the place of `SIMULATOR_OR_IOS_SDK` give your simulator value.

You can find the simulator value by running

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

This will show  like

```
OS X SDKs:
    OS X 10.11                      -sdk macosx10.11

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 9.1                         -sdk iphoneos9.1

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 9.1             -sdk iphonesimulator9.1

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 9.0                        -sdk appletvos9.0

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 9.0            -sdk appletvsimulator9.0

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 2.0                     -sdk watchos2.0

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 2.0         -sdk watchsimulator2.0
```

This way you can build your project on any specific device/simulator/os.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's hard to install Xcode from command line, and Xcode.dmg is very large.

Comment: @Quanlong: In a CI environment Xcode is the software that has to be manually installed. Your CI build invocation should use the xcode commandline tools(xcodebuild) to build your app.

Comment: Yes, but we have only one version Xcode installed on CI. And some older versions Xcode cannot be installed on newer OS X.

Comment: In that case i would prefer you to install latest xcode and install simulators manually like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137582/how-to-install-ios-7-and-onwards-simulators-in-xcode-7-beta-5

Comment: I have no GUI interface in CI

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading this 2024, ios installation of simulation for ios 17.2 has changed so here is how to fix it

download xcode normal from appstore or apple developer page
then download ios simulation runtime of your choice also, and installed using a command line

```
sudo xcrun simctl runtime add 'iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg'
```

read more here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

### [Installing and managing Simulator runtimes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes)

You can **download and install** one platform's simulators like this

```
xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

or for all platforms

```
xcodebuild -downloadAllPlatforms
```

keep in mind these are *very* large downloads.

Lastly, to get a list of the available SDKs you can use

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```