# Simulator XCode OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: xcode

Hello I am working with Xcode in OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. However I have not found any available XCode simulator with this software version. Any idea?

Comment: More details please. Xcode version, where do you try to find simulators...

Comment: XCode Version = 7.2.1 Simulators : IOS 9.2 Simulators for all mobile phones

Comment: I did not understand the later. Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32145114/1457385